# Viewing Variable in a Separate Window or Tab

Tags: r

I am kind of new to using **RStudio**...I love analyzing data by viewing it in **separate window or tab** inside the IDE..I am using **RStudio** to read **specific columns** from a **dataset**....I want to open the value stored in a variable in a separate window or tab...The variable contain only one column...Like for example i want to open the values of Y in a **separate Window** or **Tab** just like X...How can i do it?

[image]

Here is the complete code i am using

```
dataset<-read.csv('C:\\Users\\datasets\\landprice1.csv')
X = dataset[ 1:14, (1:3)]
Y = dataset[ 1:14,(4)]
```

***Note : The variable Y contain one one column have several observations while X contain 3 columns have several observations.*** Also i searched a lot on Google before coming here but could find my answer

Comment: Maybe `View(Y)`? Note that `X` is separated from `Y` because `X` is a table (a data.frame) and you can click on the arrow to see more, while `Y` is a numeric vector of length 17, there's nothing else to its structure. `View` will allow you to see all its values.

Comment: Yeah but how can i view Y...I can't see any option of viewing Y

Comment: Run `View(Y)` at the R code prompt. Also, you wrongly say that `Y` has one column, it does not, it has no columns at all like I said above.

Comment: I mean can i view it without typing any code just like i can view X

Comment: But you are seeing it, what is displayed is it.

Comment: Yeah it is displayed in a separate tab without the name of the column...Can i include the column name as well?

Comment: Look, there is **no** column to be displayed, `Y` is **just a vector**.

Comment: i am basically using this code to extract a column from the dataset for Y

Y = dataset[ 1:14,(4)]

Comment: is there some other better way to do it so that i can see it as a column with their observations?

Comment: OK, so please post the code you are using. When you do `Y = dataset[1:14, 4]`, you create a new data set, the dataset `Y`. And yes, you can create a data set with 1  column only. But we need to see the code you are using.

Comment: I now have edited the question please see it again

Comment: so basically what i want is to read a csv file...Assign X = first 3 columns and Y = Last Column(#4) and then view it in a separate window or tab

Comment: `Y = dataset[ 1:14, 4, drop = FALSE]`. No need for parenthesis. Argument `drop = TRUE` simplifies to the smallest dimension if possible and since you're only extracting one column from `dataset` it has 1 dim only becoming a vector, it's no longer a table. `drop = FALSE` doesn't simplify (drop the other dimensions, in this case the second dim).

Comment: You also don't need the parenthesis in `(1:3)`. Compare to `1:3` by running both. And I strongly suggest that you spend some time going through an introductory text on R, such as R-intro.pdf that comes with all installations of R.

Comment: That is a great help...

Thank You so much

Answer (score 1):

If you want to open a matrix or a data frame or what else you can just use View() function.

```
dataset<-read.csv('C:\\Users\\datasets\\landprice1.csv')
X = dataset[ 1:14, (1:3)]
Y = dataset[ 1:14,(4)]
View(X)
View(Y)
```